# How to insert generated list at the beginning of the result list?

Tags: c++, stl

I have one list like `list<T> result;` and in for loop I generate another list in every pass like

```
    list<T> result;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
       list<T> temp=generated_list();
        // here I want to add at the beginning of the result list values from temp list
    }
```

How to insert generated list at the beginning of the result list ? Is there better way than a loop or creating new by concatenation and then set result to result list ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::list<T>::splice` member function is most effcient way to do what you want to

```
list<T> result;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
       list<T> temp=generated_list();
        result.splice(result.begin(), temp);
    }
```